# How to create a custom groovy doclet?

Tags: groovy, doclet, groovydoc

I would like to create a custom doclet in my groovy source, but I can´t find any possibility since the *groovydoc* tool has no *-taglet* parameter. I digged a bit in the API, but no luck. Is there a way to write a custom doclet?